# Material UI Table row to open a Drawer under the row

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI (version 5.0.6) to create a Table. I want to have it so that upon clicking a row on the table, a Drawer opens below the row to display more information.

I am able to get it to recognize which row is clicked, but I don't know how to make a drawer open up just below the row that was clicked.

Here's a quick illustration of what I'm trying to do:

[image: That's the table]

That's the table, and here's what should happen after clicking, let's say row 2.
[image]

Here's the code that I've written so far:

```
<Table>
                        <TableHead>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell>column 1</TableCell>
                                <TableCell>column 2</TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                            <TableRow onClick={() => {console.log("row clicked")}}>
                                    <TableCell align="center">
                                        row 1, column 1
                                    </TableCell>
                                    <TableCell align="center">
                                        row 1, column 2
                                    </TableCell>
                              </TableRow>
                        </TableBody>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a Collapse component from MUI 5 and they also have an example of this on the documentation of the Table component [here](https://mui.com/zh/components/tables/)